# Javascript: Assign values to a multidimendional array

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I'm new at Javascript. I'm trying to assign a `string` to a `multidimensional array` with a very basic code, which is the following one:

```
var tab = document.getElementById("optionsTable").innerHTML.replace(identifier, "doc" + value);

$('#optionsTable').html('' + tab);

var table = document.getElementById("optionsTable");

for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < table.rows[i].cells.length; j++) {

    if (i == 1 && j == 0) {
      table.rows[i].cells[j] = 'apple';
      alert(table.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML);
    }
  }
}
```

I use variable `tab` because I need to change the html of the table.

When the `alert message` appears it shows that the value of the array was not changed to 'apple' as it should be. I'm not getting errors. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Deleted my answer since I'm not really versed in jQuery...

Comment: Did you perhaps mean to use `table.rows[i].cells[j].textContent = 'apple'`?

Comment: @Phil that's it! Thank you!

Comment: @Phil how can I add html like 'apple <b> Principal </b>'. Is it possible with .textContent?

Comment: you'd use innerHTML instead of textContext